# Django Two Way relationship

Tags: django, object-relationships

I am building a blog site and have models in respect of Category and Posts.  Posts have a Many to Many relationship for Category.

```
class Post(models.Model):
     categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Everything is working fine aside from the fact that in the Category list in the template I only want to load categories that actually have posts.

If a category is empty I don't want to display it, I have tried to define a relationship in Category to Post to allow me to use something like `{{ if category.posts }}`.  At the moment using another Many to Many field in Category is presently giving me an extra field in admin which I don't really want or feel that's needed.

How is best to navigate this relationship, or create one that's suitable?

Cheers
Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reverse relations` on `ManyToMany` fields. In the reverse filter, you must use the related model name (if you did not use `related_name` attribute). So in your question you can use model name as the reverse name like:

```
{% if category.post %}
```

You can also use this in your filtering functions in views:

```
Category.objects.filter(post__isnull=False)
```

Reverse relation name must be lowercase.

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 5):

Django automatically creates a field on the related model of any ForeignKey or ManyToMany relationship. You can control the name of the field on the related model via the related_name option like that:

```
class Post(models.Model):
 categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category,related_name='posts')
```

This way, your approach works without any additional fields. Btw, if you leave out the related_name argument, Django will create by default one with [field_name]_set.